# SQL, Relação entre tabelas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

A minha dúvida é sobre a relação de tabelas no [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). Em um sistema de academia eu quero fazer um relacionamento entre o aluno e a sua ficha de treino. Eu fiz um relacionamento de um para um, porque cada aluno só pode ter uma ficha.

Além disso, eu coloquei a chave estrangeira na tabela da ficha. O meu objetivo é que quando eu excluir um aluno do sistema a sua ficha seja excluída também. Porém, quando tento excluir um aluno aparece essa mensagem:

```
{com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row:}
```

Qual é o meu erro? a chave estrangeira deveria ficar na tabela do aluno?

Comment: Para fazer a exclusão de um dado de uma tabela e automaticamente excluir o dado de outra vc pode utilizar o cascade

Comment: Era esse o problema, brigadão!

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar, se puder aceitar minha resposta, eu agradeço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

Cria a tabela aluno:

```
CREATE TABLE Aluno (
    idAluno INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    idade int not null
);
```

Cria a tabela ficha:

```
CREATE TABLE Ficha(
    idFicha INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    exercicio VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    idAluno INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idAluno)
        REFERENCES Aluno (idAluno)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Observe que adicionamos a `ON DELETE CASCADE`  cláusula no final da definição de restrição de chave estrangeira.

Depois você insere dados em ambas as tabelas;

Para excluir você só vai precisar fazer isso

```
DELETE FROM Aluno WHERE idAluno = 2;
```

OBS.: Os campos das minhas tabelas eu que inventei, pois como não sei os campos que você quer, fiz dessa maneira somente para clarear a ideia!

Fonte: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Espero ter ajudado!